# PHP4 and UML: does it make sense to design an object diagram?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, uml, object-diagram

I am documenting a PHP4 system I'm building for a client. The system will be written following an object-oriented logic, using the MVC pattern. I have already sketched up a class diagram; however, I am now wondering if it makes sense to create object diagrams for such a system, since it follows the OOP model rather loosely.

The closest thing to object-oriented behavior in this system will probably be a handful of methods changing their behavior based on how they're being called, although this can't exactly be called instancing straight-up classes; would an object diagram capture anything useful from this scenario, or am I better off just skipping them altogether? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off topic, but are you sure you want to build anything in php4? It has been discontinued for year now, and the object system in particular is very hard to work with.

Comment: true, it's off topic, but i suppose it does beg for an explanation: the existing system is in PHP4, and there are things that would be very time and resource consuming if ported to PHP5. Eventually, there are plans to move some functions over to a PHP5 server, but that will be adopted only in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, UML Class diagrams are best used in an isolated context -- to describe a section of the system.

So my answer is that if you are describing a piece of your system in a document, and a UML class diagram would **help a reader understand the relevant section of the system** then you should do a diagram for that section and include it.

Doing one class diagram for the entire system is rarely, if ever, useful. And including various class diagrams without context is also rarely useful.

Be strategic in your use of UML; it's a communication tool, not a documentation tool. (Sort of like writing. Words on paper means nothing unless used and organized thoughtfully)

Comment: That makes sense, and you're absolutely right. As a matter of fact, I have organized the structure of the class diagram into packages, generalizing the structure's elements in a bird-eye fashion and breaking it down into more detailed descriptions; however, my doubt is if an object diagram would help the customer better understand the structure if I tried developing one from these elementary components. Thoughts?

Comment: My opinion simply is: if you doubt it, don't include it. I've found that it is generally extremely clear when a class diagram would be beneficial. It's hard to put in to words but for example, showing interface/class dependencies or relationships.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I wasn't expecting the choice to be as simple, but it sounds perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the flexibility of your situation conflicts with expectations of UML.

I would suggest abstracting the implementation level from your diagram (and lie) and represent the functionality of those methods as independent methods performing their own work.